# Sorting on money data type not yielding correct results

Tags: sql-server, currency

I am trying to sort the results based on a column which is of type **money**. The sorting doesn't seem to yield the desired results.

Query :

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemName, Total, 
       '$' + replace(convert(varchar,cast(Volume as money),1), '.00','') as Volume, 
   '$' +  replace(convert(varchar,cast(Average as money),1), '.00','') as Average,  
       FinalTotal     
FROM @FinalTabVariable
ORDER BY Average DESC
```

Thanks

BB

Comment: What does "working properly" mean? What values do you have, how are they ordered, and how do you want them to be ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that I see wrong.

You are using an alias of `Average` which is the name of the column that you want to order by so you are actually sorting on the `varchar` value and not the `money`. Try using:

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemName, Total, 
       '$' + replace(convert(varchar,cast(Volume as money),1), '.00','') as Volume, 
   '$' +  replace(convert(varchar,cast(Average as money),1), '.00','') as Avg,    
FROM @FinalTabVariable
ORDER BY Average DESC
```

If your `Average` column is `money`, then I am not sure why you are using `cast(Average as money)` in your query.   This seems to be unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Would a dervied query help here?

Comment: @njk I am not sure what the derived table would do in this case.

Comment: At least in MySQL, you need a derived table to do a sort on a calculated field.